# mongodb query subset of an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subset, keyword-search

I have a field `_keywords` which is an array of strings. I want to get documents where `_keywords` is a super-set of the query array.

For example:

```
db.article.insert({'_keywords': ['foo', 'foo1', 'foo2']})
```

I want to retrieve this record when I query subset of `['foo', 'foo1', 'foo2']`, eg: `['foo']` or `['foo1', 'foo2']`

EDIT:
something like:

```
db.article.find({'_keywords': {$contains: array}})
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the `$all` operator:

```
db.article.find( { _keywords: { $all: [ 'foo1', 'foo2' ] } } );
```

Source: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all

Comment: How to retrive documents where `_keywords` contains any item in the given query array. something like: `db.article.find({_keywords: {$any: ['foo1', 'foo2']}})`, which returns any documents with _keywords contains 'foo1' or 'foo2'

Comment: As I can remember, in such case you can use `$in`, for example: `db.article.find({_keywords: {$in: ['foo1', 'foo2']}})`. Check if this is right.

Answer (score 18):

In MongoDb, for array field:

```
"$in:[...]" means "intersection" or "any element in",
"$all:[...]" means "subset" or "contain",
"$elemMatch:{...}" means "any element match"
"$not:{$elemMatch:{$nin:[...]}}" means "superset" or "in"
```

Comment: Great breakdown into set theory! Helped me get my head around it since I needed the field to be a subset meaning the values passed in the query are the superset (the double negation query at the end).

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: [`$all`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operators/#_S_all) operator.
To query documents with array with superset of ['foo1', 'foo2'], use:
`db.article.find( { '_keywords': { $all: ['foo1', 'foo2'] } } );`