# Mongoid nested array query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have to query a mongoid array for value combinations inside the array.

The query array example looks like this:

```
qa = [["a","b","c"], ["a","b"],["b","c"]]
Model.any_in(:field => qa)
```

What I need in return is all models in which the `:field` contains the values(but maybe also other ones)
For example it should return Models where `:field` is `["b",'c','d']` too because of `["b","c"]` in the query.

ATM my solution is to iterate over the query array and doing `any_in` for every nested array, then combining results. This worked of course, but now if have the situation of a vastly increased query array, like about 20k "subarrays". This takes way too much time.
So far i tried combinations of `any_in` and `any_of`, all which only led me to a solution where I can query an exact match of the nested arrays, like models with `["a","b","c"]` in the `:field`

Comment: For blocks of code, just indent with four spaces or use the `{}` button.

Comment: I don't know MongoID, but MongoDB has a [$setIsSubset](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) aggregation operator that can evidently be used in queries, does that help?

Comment: According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223465/mongodb-query-subset-of-an-array), `$all` behaves like a subset query.

Comment: I tried `$all` which basically maps to just `.all` in mongoid and doesnt work unfortunately. `$setIsSubset` looks interesting but isnt implemented in Mongoid, I guess a "raw" query would work, maybe I can stitch one together.